# Why does Repeater.ItemDataBound - Event not trigger anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I do register a method for the `ItemDataBound` - Event like this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyRepeater.ItemDataBound += MyRepeater_ItemDataBound;
    // ...
}

protected void MyRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Like this, nothing is triggered, the method is never executed.
When I register the method in code-before like

```
<asp:Repeater ID="MyRepeater" runat="server" 
    OnItemDataBound="MyRepeater_ItemDataBound">
```

it does work. Why doesn't the former version work?

Thx for any tipps sl3dg3

Comment: Is page_Init really called? Is AutoEventWireUp set to true?

Comment: Yes, `Page_Init` is called. And I don't know why AutoEventWireUp is needed (I tested it with true, no difference). Other Events like `BtnSave.Click += BtnSave_Click;` (also registered in Page_Init) do work though, strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be missing `AutoEventWireup=true` in Page header in aspx file.

**Edit:**
If buttons handlers do work, perhaps it's problem with databinging - are you sure you are calling `DataBind` on `MyRepeater` or any of it's parent control? If you are calling `DataBind` manually, does it depend on `Page.IsPostBack` on your page?

Comment: True - it is set to false. But I don't quite understand why I do need this, since I explicitly do register the function for the event?

Comment: p.s.: The same works for buttons: `BtnSave.Click += BtnSave_Click;`

Comment: You need this in order Page_Init to be called. You do not set Page.Init += Page_Init explicitly and do not override OnInit, right?

Comment: @idm: `Page_Init` is registered in the Page's constructor: `this.Init += Page_Init;` - I shouldn't override, right? (I come from the VB-Corner and I don't know yet the ASP C# - way...) I wonder why the button-events do work the same way.

Comment: If buttons handlers do work, perhaps it's problem with databinging - are you sure you are calling `DataBind` on `MyRepeater` or any of it's parent control? If you are calling `DataBind` manually, does it depend on `Page.IsPostBack` on your page?

Comment: @MagnatLU: You are right! I call `DataBind()`, but I did that before registering the event. Strange though that the button-events still did work, they were also registered after the DataBind() - call.

Comment: @sl3dg3: I have edited my answer to include tip from comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `AutoEventWireUp` is set to `true`. If `AutoEventWireUp` is false your `Page_Init` method will not be executed and so the code that attaches the handler to the `ItemDataBound` event won't be executed.